# yum rpm dependency issue qpid-proton-c - how to solve?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rpm, yum, dnf

I am facing a dependency issue of a package called "qpid-proton-c"

This is the output on the cli.

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package python36-qpid-proton.x86_64 0:0.34.0-1.el7 will be updated
---> Package python36-qpid-proton.x86_64 0:0.37.0-1.el7 will be an update
---> Package qpid-proton-c.x86_64 0:0.34.0-1.el7 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: qpid-proton-c(x86-64) = 0.34.0-1.el7 for package: python2-qpid-proton-0.34.0-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package qpid-proton-c.x86_64 0:0.37.0-1.el7 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: python2-qpid-proton-0.34.0-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel-Production)
           Requires: qpid-proton-c(x86-64) = 0.34.0-1.el7
           Removing: qpid-proton-c-0.34.0-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel-Production)
               qpid-proton-c(x86-64) = 0.34.0-1.el7
           Updated By: qpid-proton-c-0.37.0-1.el7.x86_64 (epel-Production)
               qpid-proton-c(x86-64) = 0.37.0-1.el7
           Available: qpid-proton-c-0.14.0-2.el7.x86_64 (extras-Production)
               qpid-proton-c(x86-64) = 0.14.0-2.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How do I have to interpret it correctly or solve this issue?

Comment: It appears RH may have [deprecated the Python 2 package.](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/6350192) I would use the skip broken flag or reinstall the packages, as suggested in that thread. If you have enterprise support, it may help here.

Comment: ty for that info but these are different python versions, tried skip-broken of course

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by using the following command:

dnf remove qpid-proton-c -y && dnf update -y && dnf install katello-agent

The katello-agent is for Satellite registration.  It gets removed when removing qpid-proton-c, so it needs to be added back in after the update.  It also adds the qpid-proton-c package back in.